# getpeername() won't return a correct port but it returns a correct address of remote host socket language C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, p2p

I would like to ask about the getpeername() function since it returns data as the title states. I tried to get value directly from accept() function, and the result also happens the same. Value of port seems to appear randomly even though value of address is correct(address is 127.0.0.1 since I run multi-processes on an only machine). The return code of getpeername() is 0 (status = 0). I'm using gcc version 4.8.1. I write a peer 2 peer chat application without server. The following is my code:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addr_len;
int tempPort, serverSockfd;
char test[100];

// Get serverSockfd successfully....
serverSockFd = initializeSock(PORT) // In this function I initialize socket(), bind() and listen(), serverSockFd is returned by the value of socket() 


addr_len = sizeof addr;
newSock = accept(serverSockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addr_len);
tempPort = ntohs(addr.sin_port);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr.sin_addr), test, sizeof test);

printf("tempPort\t%d\n", tempPort);
printf("test\t%s\n", test);

addr_len = sizeof addr; 
if ((status = getpeername(newSock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addr_len)) != 0){  
  printf("getpeername() error!\n");
}

tempPort = ntohs(addr.sin_port);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr.sin_addr), test, sizeof test);

printf("tempPort\t%d\n", tempPort);
printf("test\t%s\n", test);
```

Thanks very much for any your comment. Here is a partial code in initializeSock():

```
sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(sd < 0)
{
  perror("SocketInit(): socket() error!\n");
  exit(1);
}

ret_val = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*) &flag, sizeof(flag));
if(ret_val == -1)
{
  perror("SocketInit(): setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) error!\n");
  exit(1);
}


gethostname(hostname,100);
host_entry = gethostbyname(hostname);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*host_entry->h_addr_list));

ret_val = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));

if(ret_val == -1)
{
  perror("SocketInit(): bind() error!\n");
  printf("For port:%d\n",port);
  exit(1);
}
....
return sd;
```

This is the code to connect to server part of a peer. ConnectSock(portOfPeerA):

```
sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  

if(sd < 0)
{
  perror("ConnectToServer(): socket() error!\n");
  exit(1);
}

if (port != 0) {

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(portOfPeerA);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*host_entry->h_addr_list));

// Do I need to bind() the port of peer B when it would like to connect to peer A? 

ret_val = connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)); 
if(ret_val == -1)
{
  printf("Error connect());
  exit(1);
}
...
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  The code all looks correct and will print the port that the client is bound to correctly.  Do you see something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which port you accept from the peer, but if the peer is connecting to your server (e.g. then one calling accept) it will connect from a (more or less) random port, that's how TCP works. It connects from a fixed port only if the peer explicitly binds to that port before connecting.

This means, that the peers originating port is not defined on the server side (where your code fragments are from) but on the client side (the side which calls connect and where you only do connect but no bind).

But, please note that it might give problems with repeated connections, if both client and server use fixed IP and ports, because then you will get the same 4-tupel in TCP which defines the connections for repeated connections and thus go into all this trouble with the various TIME_WAIT states. So it is better to let the client just pick an available port and not force it to use a specific one.

Comment: This is more or less correct. The TCP stack APIs will find an available port from the ephemeral port range for its local port if the port is unbound. On Linux, this is usually 32768 to 61000, other stacks may use the range 49152 to 65535.

Comment: Hi Steffen,thanks very much for your comment. It is a peer 2 peer chat application without server. Let say, I have 2 processes A and B. First I run A as "./p2p groupName serverPortOfA" then I run B like "./p2p groupName serverPortOfB serverPortOfA". A#Server is initialized returns A#ServerSockFd. And then B#Client is initialized, connects to the port of A#Server and returns B#ClientSockFD. In while loop, select() returns A#ServerSockFd in process A, newSock is created. Actually, the value of the port of B is incorrect when I try to call getpeername() in process A.

Comment: I can't follow your comment, but like I said - if you want a TCP connection originate from a specific port you have to explicitly bind the  socket to this port, otherwise the system will choose a port on its own.

Comment: I already bound the socket to the port as I added the more code in my question. So what do you mean bind here? Doesn't this mean I should call bind() to the port, does it?

Comment: The problem is not in getpeername which reports he correct port. If you  want to have another port reported you need to bind to it on the client side - so you better post the part which calls connect and not the one which calls accept.

Comment: You mean I should call bind also in connection part to bind the port of peer B when peer B would like to connect to server part of peer A, for example?

Comment: Yes, if you want to have connections from B originate from a specific port you need to bind them. But in most cases it it not a good idea to have this requirement, e.g. having fixed port on server and client side.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks very much for your hint. In my application, I define a specific port for every peer I initialize, for example, "./p2p portOfInitializingPeer portOfPeerIWantToConnect". And all ports are different. I do this because I would like to know the ready port of the initialized peer I will connect next time if I start another peer to join a group of peers.

Comment: Hi Steffen, I would like to take consideration into you advice. In this case, you mean I shouldn't bind a fixed port to both client and server side?(let application choose a random port from system?). If I do that, it's a little bit hard to handle since if I start a new peer, I don't know which port(also which peer as a bootstrapping) I should choose to connect to join a peer group. Can you please help me clarify your suggestion more? Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know the details of your protocol, but if you try to reuse the same tuple (source ip+port with destination ip+port) within a short time after closing a connection you will get into problems because of the time_wait states of TCP. A design with fixed ports on both sides is usually only done with UDP.

Comment: Hi Steffen, my mechanism is: First, I initialize a first peer, let say P1 as "./p2p nameGroup fixedPortOfServerP1". Then I start a new peer, called  P2 to join the group by connecting to the first peer by "./p2p nameGroup portOfServerP2 portOfServerP1". It goes on like this to create a complete graph in the network. But I think server side of a peer always use bind(), doesn't it? So in this case, I don't need to bind() in client side and just let the client choose a random port. I don't understand your point since you said that I should use bind() in client side of a peer(not in server side?).

Comment: One more question. If I let the client side of a peer, let say P1, choose a random port every time it wants to connect to server side of another peer, let say P2. Does it mean if the client side of P1 would like to connect to server side of P3, it also chooses a new random port which is different with the random port connecting with P2? If it does this, there are too many ports opened in network and it's really hard to handle the number of ports in this situation. I'm using TCP, by the way. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, when connecting to P2 it will pick probably another port than when connecting to P1 (not necessary, but usually). And if you worry about too much open ports in the network you have probably an application not really suitable for TCP.

Comment: Thanks very much Steffen. By the way, if I have a group of peers, let say it includes A, B, C. Assuming that all peers are running on a same machine(localhost). In this group, A is connected with B, B is connected with C. Now I want to connect A to C(automatically in code , not from user), If there is another peer, let say D also would like to connect to A(by user). How can I distinguish between C as an old peer and D as a new peer since both of them at the first time only connect() to A(not send() yet). Can you please help me this question? Thanks very much.

Comment: Distinguishing between users (e.g. authentication) is not part of the transport layer (TCP), which means to have implement something on the application layer - which requires sending data. On some systems you could also use the ident protocol, which gives you the system user (login) which "owns" a specific port (which has a socket bound to that port).

Answer (score 1):

`getpeername()` (and `accept()`) reports the IP and port that the remote party is locally bound to on its end. If the remote party is a client that did not call `bind()` before calling `connect()` then `connect()` performs an implicit bind to a random available port.  That is what you are seeing, and that it typical usage.  **Most** clients do not need to call `bind()` before `connect()`, but there are use cases where doing so is necessary, so don't rule it out.